# Changing Sync call to Async

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I have the following code in a library *Helper.dll*. This assembly has an embedded XML file called *Products.XML*. The method `GetProducts` works fine. But it takes few seconds to respond because it is synchronous. I want to release the UI when this load operation was going on.

There are no async calls are available for **LINQ to XML** operations like `XDocument.Load`, so I can not use `async` and `await` here.

Appreciate any answer.

```
public static class LookupUtil
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> GetProducts()
    {
        var stream = Assembly.
            GetExecutingAssembly().
            GetManifestResourceStream("Helper.Products.XML");
        var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        var document = XDocument.Load(reader);

        return document.Descendants("Products");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `Task.Run` in the calling code. Don't try to fake async behaviour in your library code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any asynchronous operations inside that method don't change it and **keep it synchronous**.

use `Task.Run` when you call it from the UI thread to offload that synchronous work to a different thread and `await` the returned task:

```
var elements = await Task.Run(() => LookupUtil.GetProducts());
```

What you are basically doing is treating a block of synchronous code asynchronously.